# Geodjango InspectDB Fails on Postgis Raster_Columns View

Tags: postgresql, geodjango, model

I am trying to generate models for an existing Postgresql database using the `Django InspectDB` command. Models are produced but a failure occurs on the raster_columns view. The error is:

```
 Exception: Could not find a geometry or geography column for "raster_columns"."extent". Inspectdb does not continue generating models for the remaining tables.
```

This makes sense because raster_columns is a system view created by Postgis. Looking at the definition of the geography/geometry_columns views, the raster_columns table is explicitly filtered out from them. Since the Extent field in raster_columns is a spatial type but does not exist in the geometry/geography_columns views, the model generation fails.

Anybody know how to get around this aside from generating the models by hand?
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doing some research for the question, I decided to comment out the raster_columns filter on the geometry_columns view.

--AND NOT (n.nspname = 'public'::name  AND c.relname = 'raster_columns'::name)

That allowed me to successfully generate the models since the raster_columns view was now cataloged in the geometry_columns view.

I then uncommented the line and recreated the geometry_columns view, returning it to the state it was in before I altered it.

Voila!

Comment: Can you explain how you solved this? I have the same problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: Let me know what specific information you need, I did an overview of how I fixed the problem in the answer. I can give you more details, just let me know.